# XCode 5: Automatic ARC conversion unavailable

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I decided to bite the bullet and convert my large years-old project to ARC.

BUT,

All of the menu items in XCode-5->Edit->Refactor which contain the term "Refactor" are dimmed and unavailable. No fiddling has been able to enable them.

If I create a new empty project, they are available, but when I open my old, large project, they are not. The project has been "updated" by XCode to be "XCode 3.2 Compatible", the most recent compatibility level it offers.

Because XCode doesn't know how to import an existing project, or even know how to accept a drag of a Group from one project to another, transporting this large, complicated project into a new project file would be a time-consuming, error-fraught undertaking that I am hoping to avoid.

Anybody seen this problem, and resolved it without starting a new project and laboriously copying files over?

Comment: Is your project set to build for 32-bit Mac? ARC is not supported there.

Comment: I am 50 mi away from it right now, but I think not -- I believe it is set up for "current OS/ Current machine" (which should be 64b), but it might have had X86+X64 selected somewhere by accident.  Because it is a corporate in-house tool, I have the luxury of not worrying about backwards compatibility _at_all_.  Regardless, that will be first on my list tomorrow morning.

Comment: Made a new clone of the entire project, checked the settings and X86+X86_64 was selected, not just x86_64. That was probably the default when the project was created.  Changing that setting did not immediately help, but I quit XCode and reopened the to-be-ARC project, and now the Convert To ARC tool is available. Thank you Greg!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer (***Thank you, Greg Parker!***) was that the platform was still set to `x86+x86_64`, which disables the ARC conversion tool.  You may also need to quit XCode and re-open the target to get the **Convert To ARC** menu item enabled.